# QuickCam Messenger Win10 compatibility 64bit driver

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, webcam, logitech-webcam

I have an old QuickCam Messenger, which gets detected from win10 but not fully recognized, thus the cam is not usable.
Under the vendor sitehttps://support.logi.com/hc/de-at/articles/360024701614--Downloads-QuickCam-Messenger
the removed all drivers for this model.

Under ftp://ftp.logitech.com/pub/techsupport/quickcam/ I found another archive. Internet research showed that is730enu.exe should be the correct driver package. When I decompress the .exe and do a driver search over the folder the device manager could not find a driver. When I select specific .inf files from the folder Windows said the file is not compatible.
It is a USB webcam and I think a generic driver should exist, what can I do.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install the drivers using the original Logitech CD and manually updating the drivers in Device Manager.

If needed you can download a copy from my Google Drive. I compressed just the driver folder - no other files are needed as you can't run the install executable on Win10 anymore:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17LawluMK_IQR-lZmUH228kXKzeeKi5h5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Which driver or files did you use exactly? It should be also on the Logitec site. Thanks for the GoogleDriver share, but I would prefer to download the driver package from the vendor.

Comment: I used the drivers from folder Drivers\x64\IM64. I went to Device manager in Windows and updated the drivers manually pointing to that folder - without running any EXE. 
Unfortunately I'm unable to prove that these are original drivers other than making a picture of the CD. I wasn't able to find the drivers on Logitech website either, otherwise I would share a link.[1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUdCd.jpg

Comment: @Rajder thanks for providing these drivers. Actually, I didn't expect that they will work for my very old Logitech QuickCam Messenger together with Win10. But the one from IM64 folder did. At least, Device Manager said "sucessfully installed" and I could get some images on VLC-Player. I find it annoying and don't understand why Logitech doesn't provide these drivers on their homepage. Instead, many questionable webpages offer "free" driver downloads which don't look like something useful but more harmful.

Answer (score 0):

This camera was designed and released for Windows XP. That's 20 years ago now.

While an updated driver was released for Windows Vista, this was a long time ago and does not support the driver model in Windows 10.

Getting Windows 10 to recognize and communicate with this device will be a matter of luck more than anything else.

Comment: Worth pointing out that a Windows Vista driver is absolutely incompatible with anything newer than Windows 8+

Answer (score 0):

I will try the cam at a later time on Linux. I think vendors should provide a generic driver for such devices (we will see how long the manufactured and directly branded China devices will work under Windows). It would help to save the environment.